# VC++ Resource Editor Problem?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, resource-files

I have a working C++ project on VS2005, I made a small change which causes a problem and I dont know what is it and how to resolve,
I added a new string entry in the resource file using the VS2005 RC editor (the default one in VS2005) but after compilation I get two compilation errors

1. Error    22  error RC2135 : file not found: BEGIN    f:\Projects\C++\TIP Project\SmartFeeder\FeederService\FeederService.rc  54
2. Error    23  error RC2135 : file not found: 0x0064   f:\Projects\C++\TIP Project\SmartFeeder\FeederService\FeederService.rc  55

when I go to these lines I found

```
1 11 
BEGIN
    0x0001, 0x0000, 0x0064, 0x0000, 0x0064, 0x0000, 0x0010, 0x0000, 0x0010, 
    0x0001, 0x0025, 0x0031, 0x000d, 0x000a, 0x0000, 0x0000
END
```

any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your resource type, 11, is wrong.  That means RT_MESSAGETABLE, the resource compiler tries to load an .mc file.  Pick something else, like 99 or MYCUSTOMRESOURCE

Answer (score 1):

Check that the rc file is using the same encoding as the rest of the application (ASCII or unicode). See this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/2f5ce42f-0547-4ad9-868f-49df5ecbc858/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the resource file has been messed up. Although without more of the file it is difficult to diagnose exactly... If you have a backup from before the change, restore it and try adding the string again. If you get the same issue all you can do is report it to Microsoft and try and invent a workaround.

Personally I never use string resources, but keep significant strings in seperate files (using plain text with custom escapes) per language, so I am no expert... I did have similar problems though when trying to use a third party resource compiler, due to missing include files.